# Installed initramfs-tools package error during update

Tags: updates

I got the following error message during update, what went wrong here ?

"Error while installing package: installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1"

Is there anybody who could help me or give me a hint how to solve this issue ?
Thank you
Michael

Answer (score 0):

I got this too. but it simply updated on the second try however would like to know what it means.[image]

Comment: I already tried that a couple times, but it doesn't work, unfortunately. But thank you, it seems that i am not alone :)